# Designing Controller in Objective C with Multiple Models

Tags: objective-c

I am designing a controller for Mac application in which I have mutiple models which gets data from mutiple sources. For example my controller class is 
DataController and Models are (HTTPData, SQLiteData)
How should I use the model classes in the controller, should I just allocate them based on some paramater for type of service, or should I use weak reference?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using generalization, that means, having a base controller, and then subclasses that handle the different types of data you support

Comment: but isn't a similar approach I am describing above. If I have a controller which a class ask for data and tell it what type of data it's looking for and then the controller goes to the mode and requests the appropriate data and returns it to the requester(view?)